# Android Studio and tabs

Tags: android-studio, ide, android-studio-3.0

What is the logic behind Android Studio's tab/space structure? I don't get it and it makes the code look like it has random tabs.

Traditionally every new level of hierarchy introduces an extra tab. That's how it's been since forever in pretty much all IDE's. So whats this exactly?

[image]

Reds here are one tab/4 spaces. So you get a double tab for some reason but only once, because then even though its also an array you get a single tab, but then you get another single tab on the next line even though "A" and "B" are on the same level of hierarchy? What is the supposed logic behind this?

I know I can set the "continuation indent" in the settings, I just dont get why you'd use double tabs in such inconsistent way?